# View layout app could not be found in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have created an application in laravel with a template. Since all the pages use the same navbar, head and scripts, i have created a layout to use on all the pages.
After a research on the problem i couldn't find where i did wrong since i got the directory correct but it still not found.
Even on a test page it doesn't work.

[image]

On the app.blade.php i got

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-footer="true">
  <head>
    @include('layouts.head')
    @yield('layouts.links')
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      @extends('layouts.navbar')
      <main>
        @yield('content')
      </main>
    </div>
    @extends('layouts.scripts')
    @yield("scripts")
  </body>
</html>
```

and on the test page i got

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')  
<h1>Test</h1>
@endsection
```

If someone could tell me what's wrong i would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you should put the `layouts` folder inside the `view` foldeer ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion try to replace `@extends('layouts.navbar')` with `@include(layouts.navbar)`. In my opinion the navbar is another view which need to inject in your `app.blade.php` file.

For reference you can look into two links

- [How @extends works](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#extending-a-layout)
- [How @include works](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#including-subviews)